# Got an empty table after set items to QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to set some items into a QTableWidget, but I got an empty table when running the program. Did I do something wrong to set them?
I show source file below, the setting function is the last part **flushTable()**.
In **dataFile.txt** I have **2021 03 20 \n some contents**, and I do get **2021 03 some contents** from **std::cout** at **flushTable**.

```
#include<iostream>

#include "MainWindow.hxx"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *Main)
     : QMainWindow(Main)
{       
        setWindowTitle("Timeline Searching system");
        this->resize(500,300);
        this->setFont(QFont("SimSun",16));
        this->Login();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::Login(){
        Login_Widget = new QWidget;
        QVBoxLayout *LoginBox = new QVBoxLayout(Login_Widget);

        QLabel *Login_Message = new QLabel;
        Login_Message->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        Login_Message->setText("时间线查询系统\n请登录");

        QFormLayout *Login_Form = new QFormLayout;
        EditUser = new QLineEdit;
        EditUser->setPlaceholderText("请输入账号。。。");

        EditPass = new QLineEdit;
        EditPass->setPlaceholderText("请输入密码。。。");
        EditPass->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
Login_Form->addRow("user name", EditUser);
        Login_Form->addRow("password", EditPass);

        QHBoxLayout *Login_Button = new QHBoxLayout;
        submit = new QPushButton("确定");
        cancel = new QPushButton("取消");
        Login_Button->addStretch(1);
        Login_Button->addWidget(submit);
        Login_Button->addStretch(1);
        Login_Button->addWidget(cancel);
        Login_Button->addStretch(1);

        LoginBox->addWidget(Login_Message,2);
        LoginBox->addLayout(Login_Form,2);
        LoginBox->addLayout(Login_Button,1);
        this->setCentralWidget(Login_Widget);

        QObject::connect(submit,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&MainWindow::LoginCheck);
        QObject::connect(cancel,&QPushButton::clicked,this,&QMainWindow::close);
}

void MainWindow::LoginCheck(){

        std::ifstream Login_File("../doc/Login_File.txt");
        if(EditUser->text().trimmed() == "crisps" && EditPass->text().trimmed() == "xxxxxxxxxxxx"){
                this->LoginSuceed();
}
        else{
                std::string User;
                std::string Pass;
                while(Login_File){
                        Login_File>>User>>Pass;
                        if(EditUser->text().trimmed().toStdString() == User &&
                                    EditPass->text().trimmed().toStdString() == Pass){
                                this->LoginSuceed();
                                return;
                        }
                        while(Login_File.get() == ' ' || Login_File.get() == '\n') continue;
                }
                QMessageBox::warning(this,"Warning!","User name or password incorrect",QMessageBox::Yes);
                EditUser->clear();
                EditPass->clear();

                EditUser->setFocus();
        }

}

void MainWindow::LoginSuceed(){
        this->resize(1000,600);
        delete Login_Widget;
        this->SearchingWindow();
}
void MainWindow::SearchingWindow(){
        Searching_Widget = new QWidget;
        QHBoxLayout *Searching_HBox = new QHBoxLayout(Searching_Widget);
        Left_Table_Box = new QGroupBox("Time");
        Time_Table = new QTableWidget;
        Time_Table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
        Time_Table->setColumnCount(4);
        Time_Table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() <<"Year"<<"Month"<<"Day"<<"Name");
        FlushTable();
        QHBoxLayout *AutoHBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
        AutoHBoxLayout->addWidget(Time_Table);
        Left_Table_Box->setLayout(AutoHBoxLayout);

        Right_Table_Box = new QGroupBox("Content");
        QVBoxLayout *Content_VBox = new QVBoxLayout;
        QGridLayout *Btns = new QGridLayout;
        content = new QLabel("Hello!");
        AddBtn = new QPushButton("添加");
        DelBtn = new QPushButton("删除");
        SrhBtn = new QPushButton("查找");
        LogoutBtn = new QPushButton("登出");
        FindEdit = new QLineEdit;
        FindEdit->setClearButtonEnabled(true);
        FindEdit->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit{padding:3,3,3,3;}");
        Btns->addWidget(AddBtn,0,0);
        Btns->addWidget(DelBtn,0,0);
        Btns->addWidget(FindEdit,1,0,1,0);
        Btns->addWidget(SrhBtn,2,0);
        Btns->addWidget(LogoutBtn,2,1);
        Content_VBox->addWidget(content,4);
        Content_VBox->addLayout(Btns,2);


        Searching_HBox->addWidget(Left_Table_Box,4);
        Searching_HBox->addWidget(Right_Table_Box,2);

        //connect(Time_Table,&TableWidget::cellClicked,this,&flushContentWidget);
        this->setCentralWidget(Searching_Widget);
}

void MainWindow::FlushTable(){
        disconnect(Time_Table,&QTableWidget::cellChanged,0,0);
        std::ifstream dataFile("../doc/dataFile.txt");
        std::string year, month, day, name, content;
        Time_Table->setRowCount(0);
        while(dataFile){
                dataFile>>year>>month>>day>>name;
                if(dataFile.fail()) break;               //exit if ends of file, must put after last cin.
                while(dataFile.get() == ' ') continue;   //avoid spaces
                std::getline(dataFile,content);
                std::cout<<year<<" "<<month<<" "<<content<<std::endl;
                Time_Table->setItem(Time_Table->rowCount(),0,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(year)));
                Time_Table->setItem(Time_Table->rowCount(),1,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(month)));
                Time_Table->setItem(Time_Table->rowCount(),2,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(day)));
                Time_Table->setItem(Time_Table->rowCount(),3,new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(name)));
                Time_Table->setRowCount(Time_Table->rowCount()+1);
        }
        dataFile.close();

        //connect(Time_Table,&TableWidget::cellChanged,this,&MainWidget::flushContentWidget);

}
```

[Screenshot of empty table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wX91.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `Time_Table->setRowCount(0);` - what do you expect? Set the rowCount accordingly in your loop.

Comment: Oh yes...so dumb :(